# edit php query to get correct json data

Tags: php, json

I have a table containing 3 columns `(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)`.

my below code fetch the json data as required to display as `(key = value)`, but also I want to display the `user_id` column like this `(user_id=value)`. now the `user_id` is displayed as a value only. how to do that.

my php code

```
 $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM mohamiusermeta  where    meta_key='websiteurl' or meta_key='profile_photo' or meta_key = 'Office' or meta_key='address_user' or meta_key='agentarea' or meta_key='offertext' or meta_key='officename' or meta_key='cover_photo' or meta_key='membertype'");
$newarray = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{

  $output[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
 $newarray[]=$output;


 }

 json_encode($newarray);

 echo(json_encode($newarray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

 mysqli_close();
?>
```

my json result display like this

```
   meta_key: meta_value
   meta_key = meta_value
```

I want to group the result with user_id column like this

```
user_id= id value
{
  meta_key: meta_value
  meta_key: meta_value
 ....
 user_id= id value
   {
  meta_key: meta_value
 meta_key: meta_value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the meta values with an multidimensional array:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $newarray)) {
        $newarray[$row['user_id']] = [];
    }
    $newarray[$row['user_id']][$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

This will create the following output:

```
{'123':{'key1': 'value1', 'key3':'value3'}, 'user2':{'key2':'value2'}}
```

So in this solution the `user_id` **itself** will become the key for your meta values and all values will be grouped on their `user_id`. If you want to have the `user_id` specified with the key `user_id` as well, you can add it to the initialization of the `user_id` meta key array:

```
if (!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $newarray)) {
    $newarray[$row['user_id']] = ['user_id' => $row['user_id']];
}
```

That will create the following result:

```
{'123':{'user_id': '123', 'key1': 'value1', 'key3':'value3'}, 'user2':{'user_id': 'user2', 'key2':'value2'}}
```